# C generates correct shell command, but system() call returns unexpected values

Tags: c, bash, terminal

I want to execute this shell command from C:
`var=19; RANDOM=$var; v1=$RANDOM;  v2=$RANDOM; echo $var $v1 $v2`
Ubuntu shell returns: `19 24421 24549` next random number based on the seed as expected. However,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char buffer[200];
for( int a = 18; a < 20; a = a + 1 ){   
     snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%s%d%s", "var=", a, "; RANDOM=$var; v1=$RANDOM; v2=$RANDOM; echo $var $v1 $v2");
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
     system(buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`var=18; RANDOM=$var; v1=$RANDOM; v2=$RANDOM; echo $var $v1 $v2
18 18 18
var=19; RANDOM=$var; v1=$RANDOM; v2=$RANDOM; echo $var $v1 $v2
19 19 19`

Command string is correct, but the values aren't updated. What causes this behavior?

---

Just in case. `System()` call is ok for scratch scripts (like this one), but shouldn't be used in production because it is resource heavy and insecure.

Comment: It most likely means that `system` is not running the same shell as you are.  (You imply you're running `bash`; it is likely that `system()` is running `sh`, and `sh` might be `dash` or some other shell.)  There are better ways to generate random numbers in C without running `system()` — though there are pitfalls in some of the ways of generating random numbers in C, too. When you see `system()`, think 'slow'.  Sometimes it is a good way to do things; sometimes (and, IMO, this is one of those times) it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu (as of 18.04) comes with three separate Bourne style shells.

There's the feature rich `bash`, used as the default user login shell:

```
$ bash -c 'var=19; RANDOM=$var; v1=$RANDOM;  v2=$RANDOM; echo $var $v1 $v2'
19 24421 24549
```

You have BusyBox's embedded `ash`, used for early booting:

```
$ busybox ash -c 'var=19; RANDOM=$var; v1=$RANDOM;  v2=$RANDOM; echo $var $v1 $v2'
19 31262 30375
```

And there's quick and lean `dash`, used as the system default shell:

```
$ dash -c 'var=19; RANDOM=$var; v1=$RANDOM;  v2=$RANDOM; echo $var $v1 $v2'
19 19 19
```

Since `RANDOM` is not a standard shell feature, it behaves differently between them. Bash and Ash give two different random sequences, while Dash just treats it as a regular variable.

When you open a terminal, the shell is `bash`. When you call `system()`, it invokes `/bin/sh` which on Ubuntu is `dash`. This is why it's different.